# Counting how many questions in each category are tagged

Tags: performance, beginner, ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

I have a homepage that shows how many questions are in a certain category which is done through tagging. The functionality is working great, it tells me how many of each there are.

However, newrelic's agent is telling me that there can be **anywhere from 16-24 database calls per request**, which seems excessive to me. How can I make this better? I just picked up rails a month or two ago, if that is relevant.

```
  def index

    @multiple_choice_questions           = MultipleChoiceQuestion.all
    @published_multiple_choice_questions = MultipleChoiceQuestion.all.published

    ## Get number of questions that are tagged with foundation
    @foundation_mcqs = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["foundation"], :wild => true).all
    @published_foundation_mcqs = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["foundation"], :wild => true).published

    @anatomy_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["anatomy", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    @behavioral_sciences_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["behavioral science", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    @biochemistry_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["biochemistry", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    @community_medicine_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["community medicine", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    @embryology_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["embryology", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    @histology_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["histology", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    @microbiology_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["microbiology", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    @pathology_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["pathology", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
   @sem1_pharma_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["pharmacology", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    @physiology_sem_one_foundation_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["physiology", "foundation", "sem1"], :match_all => true).published.size
    ##
    #


  end
```

published is a **scope defined in the model** file, by the way.

`scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }`

Comment: which gem are you using for tagging?

Comment: @KULKING ActsAsTaggable https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on